# Regex matching with a wildcard

Tags: regex, bash, glob

I am trying to check if a given string has `.rel6.` in it.  I am a little puzzled by the Bash regex behavior.  What am I missing here?

```
os=$(uname -r)                        # set to string "2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64"

[[ $os =~ *el6*    ]] && echo yes     # doesn't match, I understand it is Bash is treating it as a glob expression
[[ $os =~ el6      ]] && echo yes     # matches
[[ $os =~ .el6     ]] && echo yes     # matches
[[ $os =~ .el6.    ]] && echo yes     # matches
[[ $os =~ ".el6."  ]] && echo yes     # matches
[[ $os =~ *".el6." ]] && echo yes     # * does not match - why? *
[[ $os =~ ".el6."* ]] && echo yes     # matches

re='\.el6\.'
[[ $os =~ $re      ]] && echo yes     # matches
```

Particularly, this one:

```
[[ $os =~ *".el6." ]] && echo yes
```

Comment: If you want to check if a `.el6.` is in a string, use `[[ $os = *".el6."* ]] && echo yes`. Here, the glob pattern will be `*.el6.*` and you need `=` operator here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `=~` operator performs a regular expression matching operation on a string to its left with an expression pattern on its right. So, all RHS are regex patterns here.

The `[[ $os =~ *el6*    ]] && echo yes` does not match since the regex is `*el6*`, and `*` is a quantifier, but you cannot quantify the start of a regex, so it is an invalid regex. Note, `[[ $os =~ el6*    ]] && echo yes` will print `yes` as `el6*` matches `el` and 0+ `6`s.

A similar issue is with `[[ $os =~ *".el6." ]] && echo yes`: the regex is `*.el6.`, and it is invalid.

If you want to check if a `.el6.` is in a string, use `[[ $os = *".el6."* ]] && echo yes`. Here, the glob pattern will be `*.el6.*` and you need the `=` operator.